# TensorFlow Input dataset

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, dataset

I'm using TensorFlow and python 3.5 this is my code

```
FLAGS = tf.flags.FLAGS
tf.flags.DEFINE_integer("batch_size", "2", "batch size for training")
tf.flags.DEFINE_string("logs_dir", "logs/", "path to logs directory")
tf.flags.DEFINE_string("data_dir", "Data_zoo/Mer/", "path to dataset")
tf.flags.DEFINE_float("learning_rate", "1e-4", "Learning rate for Adam 
Optimizer")
tf.flags.DEFINE_string("model_dir", "Model_zoo/", "Path to vgg model mat")
tf.flags.DEFINE_bool('debug', "False", "Debug mode: True/ False")
tf.flags.DEFINE_string('mode', "train", "Mode train/ test/ visualize")

MODEL_URL = 'http://www.vlfeat.org/matconvnet/models/beta16/imagenet-vgg-
verydeep-19.mat'
```

`tf.flags.DEFINE_string("data_dir", "Data_zoo/Mer/", "path to dataset")`

I want to know if at this line I put the path of my data set or not.

when I did like this i've got this errors:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Balti\Downloads\FCN.tensorflow-master\FCN.tensorflow-master\FCN.py", line 223, in 
    tf.app.run()
  File "C:\Users\Balti\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\platform\app.py", line 126, in run
    _sys.exit(main(argv))
  File "C:\Users\Balti\Downloads\FCN.tensorflow-master\FCN.tensorflow-master\FCN.py", line 148, in main
    pred_annotation, logits = inference(image, keep_probability)
  File "C:\Users\Balti\Downloads\FCN.tensorflow-master\FCN.tensorflow-master\FCN.py", line 73, in inference
    model_data = utils.get_model_data(FLAGS.model_dir, MODEL_URL)
  File "C:\Users\Balti\Downloads\FCN.tensorflow-master\FCN.tensorflow-master\TensorflowUtils.py", line 19, in get_model_data
    data = scipy.io.loadmat(filepath)
  File "C:\Users\Balti\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\scipy\io\matlab\mio.py", line 142, in loadmat
    matfile_dict = MR.get_variables(variable_names)
  File "C:\Users\Balti\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\scipy\io\matlab\mio5.py", line 292, in get_variables
    res = self.read_var_array(hdr, process)
  File "C:\Users\Balti\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\scipy\io\matlab\mio5.py", line 252, in read_var_array
    return self._matrix_reader.array_from_header(header, process)
  File "mio5_utils.pyx", line 675, in scipy.io.matlab.mio5_utils.VarReader5.array_from_header
  File "mio5_utils.pyx", line 721, in scipy.io.matlab.mio5_utils.VarReader5.array_from_header
  File "mio5_utils.pyx", line 894, in scipy.io.matlab.mio5_utils.VarReader5.read_cells
  File "mio5_utils.pyx", line 673, in scipy.io.matlab.mio5_utils.VarReader5.read_mi_matrix
  File "mio5_utils.pyx", line 723, in scipy.io.matlab.mio5_utils.VarReader5.array_from_header
  File "mio5_utils.pyx", line 969, in scipy.io.matlab.mio5_utils.VarReader5.read_struct
  File "mio5_utils.pyx", line 673, in scipy.io.matlab.mio5_utils.VarReader5.read_mi_matrix
  File "mio5_utils.pyx", line 721, in scipy.io.matlab.mio5_utils.VarReader5.array_from_header
  File "mio5_utils.pyx", line 894, in scipy.io.matlab.mio5_utils.VarReader5.read_cells
  File "mio5_utils.pyx", line 673, in scipy.io.matlab.mio5_utils.VarReader5.read_mi_matrix
  File "mio5_utils.pyx", line 705, in scipy.io.matlab.mio5_utils.VarReader5.array_from_header
  File "mio5_utils.pyx", line 778, in scipy.io.matlab.mio5_utils.VarReader5.read_real_complex
  File "mio5_utils.pyx", line 450, in scipy.io.matlab.mio5_utils.VarReader5.read_numeric
  File "mio5_utils.pyx", line 355, in scipy.io.matlab.mio5_utils.VarReader5.read_element
  File "streams.pyx", line 94, in scipy.io.matlab.streams.GenericStream.read_string
  File "streams.pyx", line 81, in scipy.io.matlab.streams.GenericStream.read_into
OSError: could not read bytes

Comment: Based on `"path to dataset"`, I would think so, yes. Where's that code from? Do you have any documentation on it?

Comment: yes, this is the link to the code https://github.com/shekkizh/FCN.tensorflow, and I don't really find how to input my own dataSet even when i did like i've got errors